# Vertical text alignment in table cells

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, rich-text, table

Does anybody know how to edit vertical alignment in a table in SharePoint?

In the example below, Compare erstellen and Concur are aligned to the middle of the cell, but I want them aligned to the top of the cell. This is a simple option in Excel etc., but I can't find out how to do it in SharePoint.

Oddly, in some tables the text is automatically aligning to the top, but in others it aligns to the middle, and so for consistency I need to be able to edit it, but can't see any option to do that, only to change the horizontal alignment

[image]

Comment: Where you are updating it? in SharePoint Modern site page?

Comment: This is on any sharepoint page where I have added a table to the text web part

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to do this in SharePoint online modern page. Where you have added a table in **Text** web part, there is **no option** to set the vertical alignment.

Currently, you can only align it to left, center or right (horizontally). I even tried copy pasting the table from word document & excel. But when pasting it on SharePoint page, SharePoint automatically aligns it vertically middle position.

[image]

**Documentation**: [Add text and tables to your page with the Text web part](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-text-and-tables-to-your-page-with-the-text-web-part-729c0aa1-bc0d-41e3-9cde-c60533f2c801)

---

If you are trying to do this in office online excel file, here are the alignment options:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

pressing the return key and making some line feeds will move the text upwards and take care of the problem!